# Arrowhead issues with \ar@(dl,dr) in xypic

Tags: xy-pic, commutative-diagrams

I'm having a problem with typesetting endomorphisms of objects with "long names":

`\xymatrix{\mathcal{S}(S\times_{R}S)\ar@(dl,dr)[]_{a}}`

gives the image below, and the arrowhead is at a bad angle. Is there any way to fix this? I am asking for a solution specifically to this, so please do not suggest switching to `Tikz`.

[image]

Comment: Try `\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}`, that makes all arrow tips like the ones in Computer Modern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard arrow of Xy-pic are always wrong, in my opinion (and don't combine well with the others).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}

\xymatrix{\mathcal{S}(S\times_{R}S)\ar@(dl,dr)[]_{a}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm having a very strange problem (I'm using LyX). As soon as I added this option I get a `File does not exist` error. Do you happen to know anything about this?

Comment: @Arrow Sorry, no idea; particularly because of LyX, I'd say. What is the non existing file?

Comment: Okay, I now just have the following problem: `Option clash for package xy`: `usepackage{amsmath}` the package `xy` has already been loaded with options: `[all]`. There has now been an attempt to load it with options `[all,cmtip]`. Adding the global options `all,all,cmtip` to your `\documentclass` declaration may fix this. What do I actually need to do? The line you suggested is the first one in my preamble.

Comment: @Arrow I'm no LyX user; you need to find out how adding the `cmtip` option to the call of `xy`, which probably is just `\usepackage[all]{xy}`. This is one of the many reasons why I can't recommend using LyX: you get what *they* provide, not what *you* need.